# EJBConfigurationException IBM websphere 9.0.11

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb, ejb-3.0

so when i deployed my application in whebersphere 9.0.11 i have got this exception :
is there any config that i need to add in ejb-jar.xml

```
com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: Bean class xxxxxxxxxxx could not be found or loaded; nested exception is: 
    com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: Configured xxxxxxxxx interface is not an interface : java.lang.Object of bean xxxxxxxxxxx
```

does anyone know what I am missing?

ps i have another exception at first :

```
[4/20/21 14:13:35:582 CET] 000000ab EJBWrapper    E   CNTR5011E: The java.lang.Object class has been configured as a business or component interface for the xxxxxxxx bean. However, the class is not an interface.
```

Comment: This part of the message is indicating which configuration attribute has an issue : "Configured xxxxxxxxx interface".  For example, if xxxxxxxxx is "REMOTE", then the value of <remote> in ejb-jar.xml needs to be changed.  If you are using an EJB 3.x or later module with annotations, then you would also need to look at the annotation equivalent, so `@Remote`.  Would need more details about bean configuration, but a guess would be that you have either `@Remote` or `@Local` specified on a bean class, but the bean class implements no interface. Either use `@LocalBean`, or impelment an interface.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, what about the 2nd exception ?

Comment: where I can configure a class to be a business or component interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have an application with an enterprise bean coded something like this:

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class MyBean {...)
```

The problem is that the `@Local` annotation is present indicating there is a local business interface, but that interface is not specified anywhere. The local interface ends up defaulting to `Object`, which isn't a valid interface. A similar error would occur for `@Remote`.

When starting the application, the server will detect the configuration error and first log the `CNTR5011E` error message in the logs. Then, the server will throw the `EJBConfigurationException` in response to an attempt to access the application, which is later wrapped in the ContainerException. Both the error message and the exception are for the same problem.

The Enterprise Bean specification provides many ways to configure bean interfaces:

**No-interface view**

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {...)
```

Simply remove the `@Local` annotation (or replace with `@LocalBean`) and the bean class (`MyBean`) will become the interface. Similar to a local business interface.

**Business Interface**

```
@Stateless
@Local(Cart.class)
public class MyBean {...)
```

Add an interface as an attribute of the `@Local` annotation, and that becomes the local business interface. Similarly you may use `@Remote`, or both, but the same interface cannot be both local and remote. You may specify multiple local or remote interfaces if you would like.

**Business Interface - implemented**

```
@Stateless
@Remote
public class MyBean implements RemoteCart {...)
```

Change the class to implement an interface, then that becomes the remote/local business interface, depending on the annotation. The implemented interface would default to a local business interface if neither annotation is present.

**Business Interface - annotated interface**

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements RemoteCart {...)

@Remote
public interface RemoteCart {...)
```

When an interface is annotated `@Local` or `@Remote`, then it becomes a local or remote business interface if the bean class implements it.

**Component Interface (EJB 2.x API)**

```
@Stateless
@LocalHome(CartLocalHome.class)
public class MyBean {...)
```

Using the `@LocalHome` or `@RemoteHome` annotation provides an EJB 2.x API component interface. The `EJBLoclHome`/`EJBHome` interface class is specified on the annotation, and defines the component home interface, the component interface is then determined from the return value of the `create` method on the home interface.

**Interfaces declared in ejb-jar.xml**

```
<session>
    <ejb-name>MyBean</ejb-name>
    <remote-home>CartRemoteHome</remote-home>
    <remote>CartRemote</remote>
    <local-home>CartLocalHome</local-home>
    <local>CartLocal</local>
    <business-local>Cart</business-local>
    <business-remote>RemoteCart</business-remote>
    <local-bean/>
    <ejb-class>MyBean</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
</session>
```

Everything that can be done with annotations can also be done in XML. Note that `@Local` corresponds to `<business-local>` and `@Remote` corresponds to `<business-remtoe>`.  A bean may be visible through several different interfaces, as shown in the example; however, there needs to be at least one.